# Could not load the following font on WebSphere

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports, websphere, jasperserver

Getting the following error while trying to export to a PDF using *JasperReports*.

**Error when the error message is being printed is as follows:**

Could not load the following font :

pdfFontName   : Arial.ttf

pdfEncoding   : Identity-H

isPdfEmbedded : true]

**My JRXML**
`<textElement>
<font pdfFontName="Arial.ttf" isPdfEmbedded ="true" pdfEncoding ="Identity-H"/>
</textElement>`

**Using:**
WebSphere Application Server version 7
*JasperReports* version 3 jar

The Arial.ttf font file is present in the .../web-inf/classes and the default location of fonts in a unix machine.

I have almost no knowledge in *JasperReports* and need to debug this issue. Kindly help me with the things I might be missing/overlooked or of more specific information is required about any part.

Comment: Are you talking about custom Java application or about *JasperReports Server*?

Answer (score 1):

You may try copying the font ttf file into:

```
<WAS_INSTALLATION>java/jre/lib/fonts
```

and then restart the WAS server.